Тень от модального окна пропадает при щелчке мышью не на этом окне
Мне нужно показать всплывающее окно с тенью. Вроде бы сделал, как написано в статьях, но в одном случае точно работает не правильно: когда я вызываю всплывающее окно, которое рисует нужную мне тень в диалоговом режиме (всплывающая форма модальная), а затем я нажимаю на основную форму (за пределами модальной всплывающей формы), тогда тень скрывается за главным окном приложения (в этом случае обычное модальное окно мигает, показывая, что действия можно совершать только на этом модальном окне). Если я переключусь на другой процесс в Windows, а затем переключусь на мою работающую программу, то тень обновится и будет выглядеть так, как должна. Вопрос: как предотвратить скрытие тени под основной формой?
Привожу код ниже:
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace TestShadow
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                PopupForm popupForm = new PopupForm();
                popupForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                popupForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                popupForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                var topLeft = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
                popupForm.Location = new Point(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y + button1.Height);
                popupForm.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        public class PopupForm : Form
        {
            const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
            protected override CreateParams CreateParams
            {
                get
                {
                    const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x200;
                    const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
                    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                    cp.ClassStyle |= CS_NOCLOSE;
                    cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
                    return cp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

Картинки:



Пробовали воспроизвести такое например в .NET 8 на новых винформах? Быть может этот баг уже давно исправлен.

Я считаю, что такой баг можно исправить не за счет нового фреймворка, а только переписав WndProc,   что я и сделал по совету одного программиста. Всё заработало

На что только не готовы люди ради того чтобы ничего не обновлять. Ну ок.

Никакое обновление - багов не убирает. Частично может и убирает. Но баги всё равно остаются. Т.е. если логически - некая "надежда", "вера" и прочая ересь в то, что кто то или что то - все баги исправит - это и есть путь "вникуда".

И второе. Никакое обновление - ничего не даёт, потому как любое обновление = детектирование багов. Ну можно менять шыло на мыло и пытаться разбираться в чужих системах. Но сильно проще накарячить своё. И тогда не нужно разбираться в чужом забагованном бесполезном треше. Разбираться в своём - сильно выгодней, чем разбираться в чужом. По определению. И на что только люди не пойдут, лишь бы своего не иметь.

По совету одного программиста Jimi я добавил следующий код:
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{ 
  switch (m.Msg) 
  { 
    case WM_NCACTIVATE: 
      SetWindowPos(Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3); 
      break; 
    default: 
      break; 
  } 
  base.WndProc(ref m); 
}


Вместо этого SetWindowPos вызова разве нельзя просто задать popupForm.TopMost = true;? А WndProc убрать вовсе?

Работает только с WndProc, TopMost = true не решает проблему, тень прячется за главную форму
